# Java Exceptions, pass data from try block to the handler

Tags: java, android, exception, malformedurlexception

I am catching a `MalformedURLException` and I would like the stack trace to include the malformed url.

The methods `getMessage()` and `getLocalisedMessage()` don't show the entire URL, I cannot reference the url declared in the try block and if I initialise the variable outside the block I get an error pointing out that the URL might not ever get initialised.

I am wondering if there is a way to pass the url from the try block to the handler.

Comment: When you declare the URL outside the `try` block init it to `null`.

Comment: @alfasin Thanks! Please put this as the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare the `URL` outside the try block init it to `null`

Answer (score 2):

assuming your code is like this

```
try {
      throw new MalformedURLException("message");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.getStackTrace();
      e.getCause(); // in this case e.getCause() == e
      e.getMessage();
}
```

in the catch block you can only access the stack trace, the message and the exception.

If e.getMessage() contains the full URL you can access the full URL otherwise there is no solution and you have to work on the code that trows the exception